# Dynamic content loaded from CMS. Staff job description to show once clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, content-management-system

I am creating a staff members page where it has 3 staff members in a row 33% each of the row and once clicked on a member it displays there description below. The description is 100% of the container. My problem is, once clicked on image it pushes the next two staff members down.

The staff members will be loaded via a CMS, there nothing can be hard coded.

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/BSN5u/1/

HTML:

```
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="job-desc"><img src="../images/our-people/staff1.png" alt="staff1" width="191" height="191"></a></li>
        <li>Jon doe</li>
        <li>09 548 5554</li>
        <li>jon@gmail.com</li>
      </ul>

       <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, tempora, libero, ipsa maxime facere ullam harum ad iusto laborum minima magni officia provident aut obcaecati quaerat fugiat labore qui aliquam.</p>

       <ul>
        <li><img src="../images/our-people/staff1.png" alt="staff1" width="191" height="191"></li>
        <li>Jon doe</li>
        <li>09 548 5554</li>
        <li>jon@gmail.com</li>

      </ul>

      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, tempora, libero, ipsa maxime facere ullam harum ad iusto laborum minima magni officia provident aut obcaecati quaerat fugiat labore qui aliquam.</p>


         <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="staff1" width="191" height="191"></li>
        <li>Jon doe</li>
        <li>09 548 5554</li>
        <li>jon@gmail.com</li>

      </ul>

      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, tempora, libero, ipsa maxime facere ullam harum ad iusto laborum minima magni officia provident aut obcaecati quaerat fugiat labore qui aliquam.</p>

  </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>

      $( ".job-desc" ).click(function() {
          $( ".description" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: Could you create a demo, including your CSS etc.

Comment: Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/BSN5u/1/

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add CSS, i have added JS Fiddle. My problem is i cant get the 3 images to stay in a row once clicked as per my fiddle. Paragraph will need to be attached to staff member in one block so CMS can loop through blocks and add multiple entries

Comment: I can think of a way like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BSN5u/6/) Also you can just get it to place the desc is the other div I have creating while in the loop.

Comment: Thanks! Very close. I need the <p> the be straight after the <UL> as content will be loaded from CMS

Comment: You can just loop it to insert each `<p>` in order into the `div` at the bottom can you not?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

On page load, add some CSS that changes the style of .description elements to none. 
Then when .job-desc is clicked, toggle the visibility.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.description').css('display','none');

        $( ".job-desc" ).click(function() {
          $( ".description" ).toggle();
    });
});
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iammarcthomas/PkeYV/

Hope that helps,
Marc